# The movement of moon shadow during eclipse

Tags: cosmology

Why is the movement of the moon's shadow during a solar eclipse (witnessed from the satellite)
From left to right
While it should be the opposite if the Earth rotates from left to right
Whereas, the relative motion of the Moon is about

The earth is

27 longitude within an hour

Within four hours.

Only the supposed movement of the Earth affects here
So how to solve
This puzzle

Answer (score 0):

It is because the time here is the time it take the moon to revolve around the Earth. But while observing the moon from from earth we also have to account the earth rotation about its own axis, which has a time of near 24 hr so even though the moon is revolving from right to left but because of high speeds of earth rotations we observe it to moving apparently in the opposite direction

Answer (score 0):

The Moon moves slower in the sky than the Sun (a Moon day takes 24.8 hours) so relatively to the Sun it appears to move from West to East in the sky.